# Determine SMTP server technology

Tags: smtp, email-server

I know how to determine who provides the SMTP servers for a domain name (DNS MX RR, DNS PTR RR, etc) but is there a way to determine **what** the SMTP servers are for a domain name (Microsoft Exchange Server, etc) when there is no webmail.

telnet | TCP 25 | `EHLO` doesn't report much.

I'm looking for something like https://builtwith.com but for email.

Comment: Entirely up to the email admins / postmaster to determine what the smtp banner says, how it responds and what commands are available.  `nmap -sV -P0 -p 25` is the non-polite way to test for this.  Your IP may get blocked.  The polite method would be to email `postmaster@domain.tld` and ask.

Comment: @Aaron Okay, thank you. For others' information: `-sV: Probe open ports to determine service/version info`, `-Pn: Treat all hosts as online` (`-P0` been superseded by `-Pn` according to https://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as answer from above discussion in the comments and updated nmap usage as `-P0` will be deprecated:

The information disclosed by an SMTP server is entirely up to the email admins and/or postmasters to determine what the smtp banner says, how it responds and what commands are available.

**Non Polite Enumeration Method**

You can use the NMAP scanner to determine (in most cases) the make and version of software being used:

```
nmap -sV -Pn -p 25
```

This is generally considered to be impolite, as it will leave anomalous log entries on their server and may even trigger automated blocking of your IP address.

**The Polite Method of Server Enumeration**

The most polite and preferred method would always be to email postmaster@domain.tld and ask them what they are running and sort out any interoperability issues with them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Aaron's recommendation, https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap worked very well.